# Css Parallax with different placement of fixed and relative sections

Tags: css, html, parallax

i need help in creating a css parallax page just like http://www.wideeyecreative.com

I want the parallax to be in this format:

[Fixed div] 
[Scrolling div]
[Scrolling div]
[Fixed div]
[Scrolling div]
[Scrolling div]
[Fixed div]

Comment: There is this fiddle that has something similar but it doesn't work because when i try to add a fixed div in between two scrolling divs, it goes to the top of the page because of the "top:0" in the css instead of being in its location.

Need help doing this is CSS or with JS also

Link to     [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMpu4/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Make multiple fixed divs and show/hide them based on scroll position.
Also make sure to add some space between the scrolling divs where the fixed div should show by using margin top or bottom.

Comment: I'll make a js fiddle.